# Formulario nao pode preencher todo de uma vez

Tags: php, api

será que alguem pode me salvar?
é um formulário onde o usuário coloca o id do Pokémon e ele preenche de acordo com a API.

só que ele está preenchendo automático todos os outros campos, ou qdo mudo preenche apenas o primeiro e nenhum maisinserir a descrição da imagem aqui

não consigo permitir que o usuário faça um a um

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="jog1">Jogador 1</label>
              
                <input name="pok1" type="number" class="form-control" id="pok11" placeholder="Nome do seu Pokemon" >
                  <div class="button floatLeft">
                  <input class="pokNome" type="text" disabled="disabled">
                  <input class="pokBase" type="text" disabled="disabled">
                  </div>
                
                <br>

                <input name="pok1" type="number" class="form-control" id="pok12" placeholder="Nome do seu Pokemon" >
                  <div class="button floatLeft">
                  <input class="pokNome" type="text" disabled="disabled">
                  <input class="pokBase" type="text" disabled="disabled">
                  </div>

                <br>

                <input name="pok1" type="number" class="form-control" id="pok13" placeholder="Nome do seu Pokemon" >
                  <div class="button floatLeft">
                  <input class="pokNome" type="text" disabled="disabled">
                  <input class="pokBase" type="text" disabled="disabled">
                  </div>
```

```
JS

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pok11").focusout(function(){



    var pokemon = $("#pok11").val();
    var pokemonAPIURL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1";


    
    $.ajax({
    url: pokemonAPIURL,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      //console.log("GetPoke by ID");
      console.log(data);

      $(".pokNome").val(data.name)
      $(".pokBase").val(data.base_experience)

    }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Problema resolvido com

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(".pokload").focusout(function() {
    carregarPokemon(this.id);
  });
```